# VB.NET Linq searching rows in datagridview based on column

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

NET and Linq

And, I have a question about using Linq to search data in the DataGridView

for example I have table like

```
    ---------------
ID| Name| Task
1 | bob | Developer
2 | Sam | manager
3 | Dan | Developer
```

I would like to search developer on the data grip view and put into list

What I tried to do was...

```
Dim qur = (From r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows Where r.Cells(2).Value.ToString = "Developer").ToList
```

However it keeps return null error..

I am not really sure why it is returning null error and how to solve this problem...

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

thanks

Comment: In debug mode you should be able to identify what value is null.  What value is null?  My initial guess is there is an empty row for a new value which has a null value for cell(2)

Comment: Thanks!! I just realized that AllowUserToAddRows = True... it made extra null row!!! thanks!!

Comment: Your probably better off doing the query on the datasource - not the DGV.